# Getting Rid of an Object's Reference

Tags: java, variables, object, reference, instance

I want to get rid of each object's reference in my tester class, but I'm getting errors. The methods I'm using were given to me in notes but not sure if they're correct.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Here's my code:

```
public class Bicycle {

// Instance Variables
private String name; // Owner's name
private int age; // Owner's age
private char gender; // Owner's gender
private static int instanceCounter = 0;

// Default Constructor - doesn't take in values
public Bicycle() {
    this("Not Given", 0, 'U');
    instanceCounter++;
}

// Parameter constructor
public Bicycle(String name, int age, char gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    instanceCounter++;
}

// Getter and setters
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public char getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(char gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public int countInstances(){
    return instanceCounter;
}
}
```

Tester:

```
public class BicycleTester {

  public static void main(String args[]){


    // Instance one
    Bicycle bicycle1 = new Bicycle(null, 0, 'U');
    bicycle1.setName("John");
    System.out.println("Name: " +bicycle1.getName());
    bicycle1.setAge(18);
    System.out.println("Age: " +bicycle1.getAge());
    bicycle1.setGender('M');
    System.out.println("Gender: " +bicycle1.getGender());

    System.out.println("");

    // Instance two
    Bicycle bicycle2 = new Bicycle(null, 0, 'U');
    bicycle2.setName("Mary");
    System.out.println("Name: " +bicycle2.getName());
    bicycle2.setAge(23);
    System.out.println("Age: " +bicycle2.getAge());
    bicycle2.setGender('F');
    System.out.println("Gender: " +bicycle2.getGender());

    System.out.println("");

    // Instance three
    Bicycle bicycle3 = new Bicycle(null, 0, 'U');
    bicycle3.setName("Billy");
    System.out.println("Name: " +bicycle3.getName());
    bicycle3.setAge(15);
    System.out.println("Age: " +bicycle3.getAge());
    bicycle3.setGender('M');
    System.out.println("Gender: " +bicycle3.getGender());

    System.out.println("");

    // Three ways to get rid of object's reference
    void go() {
        Life bicycle1 = new Life();
    }

    Life bicycle2 = new Life();
    bicycle2 = new Life();

    Life bicycle3 = new Life();
    bicycle3 = null;

}

}
```

Comment: Please post the errors as well as what you mean by "getting rid of object reference". Do you mean  you want it to be eligible for garbage collection?

Comment: @MarcusWidegren yes that's what I want

Answer (score 2):

Ok Ma'am Lets go over the basics again.

We will start with the difference between an *Object* AKA *instance* and a *reference*.

`Life bicycle2 = new Life();`

Here, `bicycle2` is a *reference* it will be on the *Stack*. The reference points to the `instance`created by the call to `new Life()`. The instance will be on the *Heap*

**You can't get rid of an Object's reference. You can get rid of an instance**. 
There is only one wayof doing that.

1. Set the reference pointing to the instance to `null` or `to some other instance`
   example : `Life bicycle2 = new Life();`
          `bicycle2 = null;// the instance created above will be eligible for GC`

or you could also do :

`Life bicycle2 = new Life();`
`bicycle2 = new Life();`// the life instance created above will be discarded.

Note that : a reference is *scope dependent* once it goes *out of scope*, it will not be accessible. I don't think you arre talking about that here.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your no-argument constructor, you're incrementing instanceCounter twice - once when you call the other constructor with parameters, and once when that completes in the no-args constructor as well.

You're also not decrementing the count anywhere, so if you're using that as a means to keep track of how many instances of your class are in memory, your count will be off.